# How to reduce execution time (Python)

Tags: python, optimization

I'm trying to solve this problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/tests/2h92ckdchlg/
(My job is to count how many frequencies value fit in all the intervals of filterRanges)

But I'm facing an "Terminated due to timeout" after 10 seconds of code execution.

My solution is this one:

```
def countSignals(frequencies, ranges):
    ranges = [range(i[0], i[1] + 1) for i in ranges]
    return sum(1 if all(f in r for r in ranges) else 0 for f in frequencies)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    frequencies_count = int(input().strip())

    frequencies = []

    for _ in range(frequencies_count):
        frequencies_item = int(input().strip())
        frequencies.append(frequencies_item)

    filterRanges_rows = int(input().strip())
    filterRanges_columns = int(input().strip())

    filterRanges = []

    for _ in range(filterRanges_rows):
        filterRanges.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

    result = countSignals(frequencies, filterRanges)

    print(result)
```

I can only edit the countSignal function!

How my code runs:

I receive a number, equivalent to len(frequencies). After that, I get each one of the elements that will compose the frequencies list. Then I receive len(filterRanges) and the dimension of each one of the lists that compose the matrix filterRanges. At the end, I get the values that compose each list.

Input example:

```
5 #-> len(frequencies)
20 #-> frequencies[0]
5 #-> frequencies[1]
6 #-> frequencies[2]
7 #-> frequencies[3]
12# -> frequencies[4]
3 #-> len(filterRanges) -> filterRanges is a matrix
2 #-> lenght of the lists that compose filterRanges
10 20 #-> filterRanges[0] = [10,20]
5 15 #-> filterRanges[1] = [5,15]
5 30 #-> filterRanges[2] = [5,30]
```

In this case, for example, it would return 1, because only "12" fits all the intervals.

I've been through 12 of 15 tests with this code, getting timeout error on the last 3. How can I optimize my code so I'm able to pass in all of these tests?

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Edited.
Will run in O(n+m). Just merging overlapping intervals.

```
#filter contains time intervals
#frequencies contains the elements
#example -> filter = [[1,50],[15,23],[16,40],[8,45],[14,56]]
start = -1
end = 10000000000
flag = True
l = list()
for i in range(len(filter)-1):
    temp = filter[i]
    temp1 = filter[i+1]
    if temp[0] <= temp1[0] <= temp[1]:
        start = max(start,temp[0])
        end = min(end,temp1[1],temp[1])
    elif temp1[0] <= temp[0] <= temp1[1]:
        start = max(start,temp[0])
        end = min(end,temp1[1],temp[1])
    else:
        flag = False
        #print("cant be done")
        break
if flag:
        #print(start,end)
    for i in frequencies:
        if start <= i <= end:
        l.append(i)

return l
```

Comment: I think you have a typo: `target >= i[0] and target <= i[0]`. That's equivalent to `target == i[0]`

Comment: np. Did you know you can do `i[0] <= target <= i[1]` in Python? ;)

Comment: I tried this too, but this for loop is not even close to optimized...  I got 10/15 with this solution. Anyway, thanks for helping :)

Comment: Okay. So now observing the problem you can see the if all the intervals are intersecting and than a number lie between maximum opening interval and minimum closing interval it will be counted. i.e. happens in your case the maximum opening interval is 10 and minimum closing interval is 15. And 12 is the only one which lie in between 10 and 15. And while merging the interval if we get any interval not intersecting that means no number can lie between that 2. For eg. [10,30] and [35,60] so no number satisfy this case.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example:

```
frequencies = [20, 5, 6, 7, 12]
ranges = [[10,20], [5,15], [5,30]]
```

The problem you are trying to solve is to determine how many items from the `frequencies` list meet the criteria `10 <= f <= 15` where `f` is the frequency, `10` is the largest start value for a range and `15` is the smallest end value for a range. You first need to determine the upper and lower bounds for this criteria check.

```
lower_bound = None
upper_bound = None
for r in ranges:
    if lower_bound is not None:
        lower_bound = max(lower_bound, r[0])
    else:
        lower_bound = r[0]
    if upper_bound is not None:
        upper_bound = min(upper_bound, r[-1])
    else:
        upper_bound = r[-1]
```

Now you can iterate through the `frequencies` list and count how many frequencies meet the criteria. There is a special case where the lower bound may be larger than the upper bound, in this situation there is no solution so the return value should be `0`.

```
count = 0
if (lower_bound < upper_bound):
    for f in frequencies:
        if lower_bound <= f <= upper_bound:
            count += 1
```

This may be sufficient but if there are duplicates in the list then you will waste time checking them - [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) would be a good option to use to cover this scenario.

```
import collections
freq_counter = collections.Counter(frequencies)
count = 0
if (lower_bound < upper_bound):
    for f in freq_counter.keys():
        if lower_bound <= f <= upper_bound:
            count += freq_counter[f]
```

Now all that remains is to return the value of `count`.

```
return count
```